# best way to design scheme in django when we have diff categories and products

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am designing  django models for a E-commerce market place site where user can buy 4 type of products . Like I have  4 type of diff models for them .

**For clothes**

```
class Merchandise(models.Model):
    adOwner = models.ForeignKey(VendorProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    imagesMerchandise = models.ManyToManyField(merchandiseImages)
    productName = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    availableQuality=models.IntegerField()
    color=models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=50 , null=False , blank=False)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=250 , null=False , blank=False)
    is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.productName)
```

**for Rent a Car**

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    adOwner=models.ForeignKey(VendorProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    carImages=models.ManyToManyField(Image)
    make=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    modelName=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    registrationNumber=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    modelYear=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    modelColor=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    carType=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    fuelMileage=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    SeatingCapacity=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    vehicleCondition=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    fuelType=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    price=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    registerIn=models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.modelName)
```

**book a hotel**

```
class Accommodation(models.Model):
    adOwner = models.ForeignKey(VendorProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hotleImages = models.ManyToManyField(HotleImages)
    accommodationTitle=models.CharField(max_length=150)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    accommodationName = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    checkIn = models.TimeField()
    checkOut = models.TimeField()
    # accessibility = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    pets = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    child = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**Create a Activity**

```
class ActivityOrganizer(models.Model):
    adOwner = models.ForeignKey(VendorProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    activityImage = models.ManyToManyField(ActivityImage)
    activityName = models.CharField(max_length=50 , null=False, blank=False)
    activityId = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False)
    ageSuggestion = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False)
    openTime = models.TimeField()
    closeTime=models.TimeField()
    expiryDate = models.DateField()
    availableQty = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    needToBring = models.CharField(max_length=50 , null=True , blank=True)
    personsAllowOnOneTicket = models.IntegerField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50 , null=True , blank=False)
    specialNotes = models.CharField(max_length=250 ,null=True , blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250 , null=True , blank=True)
    is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**Now I made a order Table like this**

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    order_number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    total_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    ordertime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user_note=models.CharField(max_length=150 , null=True, blank=True)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=150 , null=True, blank=True)
    order_status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS , max_length=50)
    payment_status=models.BooleanField(default=0)
```

Now I am confuse how to bind all these 4 categories to my order object. as If its a for single category I can simply create a foreign key with order model. But How can I bind all these (as user can pick 1,2,3,4 number of categories ) so if user select Accommodation , and Vehicle categories products  how I can save 2 categories null in foreign key.  Any help would be highly appreciated . thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have small number of products (4 in your case) and for each order only one item of a type can be ordered, then you can simply add those to the `Orders` model with nullable fields

```py
class Orders(models.Model):
    order_number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    total_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    ordertime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user_note=models.CharField(max_length=150 , null=True, blank=True)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=150 , null=True, blank=True)
    order_status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS , max_length=50)
    payment_status=models.BooleanField(default=0)
    merchandise = models.ForeignKey(Merchandise, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    accommodation = models.ForeignKey(Accommodation, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    activity_organizer = models.ForeignKey(ActivityOrganizer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

To list all the orders of a specific category, exclude all the orders with null in given field.

```py
Orders.objects.exclude(merchandise__isnull=True)
```

Also if only a single category product is ordered rest 3 fields will be null, if you want to enforce that business logic then you can check for it by creating a signal.

Comment: thanks for reply . these are my categories so If I have to keep record of every product ordered against each category then what I will do ?

Comment: And If I dont want  'for each order only one item of a type can be ordered' this then it will not work for me ?

Comment: just 1 case is not handled here . If I want to purchase 3 products of merchandise , 2 of accommodation ,1 of activity_organizer  then I have  to create seprate models of all these categories ?

Comment: Yes that is true if you want a one order to many products relation, you'll have to create a separate table for all categories.

Comment: can you give a small example of it please  ?  I will accept as a answer for sure

Comment: For all categories separate tables ? like 4 new tables with ForeignKey  relation with actual tables ?

Comment: any help regarding last issue?